# Linguistic Sorting and String Searching is fetching incorrect data in oracle

Tags: oracle11g, nls-sort, nls-comp

I have a table "Audit" in Oracle 11g database. The table has a column "Account_Name".
The "Audit"."Account_name" column has the following data: "Guest", "feeder_1", "feeder_2", "feeder_3" etc.

I have created the following index on the column "Audit.Account_Name".

```
CREATE INDEX AUDIT_IX9_CI ON AUDIT (NLSSORT("ACCOUNT_NAME",'nls_sort=''BINARY_CI'''));
```

From JDBC code I am first executing the below statements and then executing the actual query to fetch the data from "Audit" table.

```
connection.prepareStatement("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC"); //line1

connection.prepareStatement("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI");  // line2
```

//This is the code that gets executed to fetch the data

```
connection.prepareStatement("select account_name from audit where  (ACCOUNT_NAME  like  'f%' ) ");//line3

rs = pst.executeQuery();//line4

while(rs.next()){
     String accountName = rs.getString("account_name");
     System.out.println("account name "+accountName);
}
```

The above query is fetching all the data from the table including values like "Guest". I'm excepting the query should fetch only rows where Account_name starts with 'f', but looks like by NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP is fetching incorrect data.

I found out that if I comment "line2" it fetches the data correctly. Can anyone suggest why these options are not working properly.

I executed the query from JDBC code on the same connection object.

```
select PARAMETER, value from nls_session_parameters

NLS_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY = AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY = $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY = AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = .,
NLS_CALENDAR = GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN
NLS_SORT = BINARY_CI
NLS_TIME_FORMAT = HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT = HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY = $
NLS_COMP = LINGUISTIC
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = BYTEs
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP = FALSE
```

This issue is raised in production environment. So earlier I have written a standalone Java code using JDBC to check if I get the same issue as in production.

I have now written a Oracle procedure, in the procedure first the NLS_COMP and NLS_SORT parameters are set and then the search query is executed (used a CURSOR here) and later resetting NLS_SORT=BINARY. The results are same, I get the same issue.

```
explain plan for
  select account_name from audit where account_name like 'f%'


Plan hash value: 1078245361

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |               |    10 |  2580 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| AUDIT_IX9     |    10 |  2580 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("ACCOUNT_NAME" LIKE U'f%')
       filter("ACCOUNT_NAME" LIKE U'f%')

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

After executing the following query I got Character Set as "WE8MSWIN1252";

select value into char_set  from nls_database_parameters  where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

Comment: What is your NLS_LANGUAGE set to? Or your Java locale if that's easier to find out. (You can query NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS over JDBC to get the actual settings you're using).

Comment: select PARAMETER, value from nls_session_parameters

NLS_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY = AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY = $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY = AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = .,
NLS_CALENDAR = GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN
NLS_SORT = BINARY_CI
NLS_TIME_FORMAT = HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT = HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY = $
NLS_COMP = LINGUISTIC
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = BYTEs
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP = FALSE

Comment: I got these parameters and values after executing query from JDBC code on the same connection object. Here i am aligning the above parameters.

Comment: Are you able to run the same alter and query statements in another client and get the correct results? If so can you add that and that session's NLS settings to the question too? And maybe the NLS_DATA_PARAMETERS settings. And if that also errors, can get get the explain plan instead, include the predicate information? I think it's an NLS issue but I can't quite see how to get this effect; possibly it's a character set conflict I can't reproduce. Or I may be way off...